# place value into input box from query string not working

Tags: javascript, string, input

how can I take the value of a query string and place it into an input box? Currently I have:

```
<input type="text" name="spouse" id="spouse"  value="<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Name: " + Request.QueryString("spouse"));

    </script>"/>
```

But that only takes the script take and all of its contents and places it into the input box.

I would like to be able to take my query string that is coming from this code:

```
<tr >
<td><input type="text" name="n1" value="Duck, Donald"  /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="n2" value="Daisy"  /></td>
<td><input type="button"  value="Show" title="Show"  
           onclick="location.href='example123.html?name=' + escape(this.form.n1.value)+ '&spouse=' + escape(this.form.n2.value);" />

</td>
```

and have the value for name or spouse appear inside of an input box. What is the proper way to place a value into an input box from a query string?

Comment: That first example isn't even capable of running (maybe on IE), as there are unescaped quotes.

Comment: I'd use the onLoad or something like that. If you use onClick, your user will lose their data any time they click on the control.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET code and are you using any javascript frameworks (where some of this work may be abstractable for you to save you some headache)?

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString` is not a native JavaScript function. Use the `document.location` object and parse out the value you want.

Comment: how do you use document.location to parse out a value?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the onload function to perform the action you need. This calls your function once the document has been fully loaded and so you know all tags in the html will exist at this point and be can be referenced properly.

eg.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Value Setting</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = (function() {
               document.getElementById('spouse').value = "one way";
               document.forms[0].elements[1].value = "another way";
               /* note elements refers to only input children */
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myform">
        <div>
            <input id="first-field" value="first-field" onchange="this.value += ' an example';"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <input id="spouse" value="spouse"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can't embed elements in attributes as that isn't valid html. Though some attributes can get evaluated as javascript. Namely attributes such as action, onchange, onclick and so on.

Comment: how do you retrieve the value from the query string to use it where spouse is from the sending page?